# Building GMP with NDK

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-ndk, gmp

I am trying to use msys2 on windows to build gmp for Android with the ndk toolchain. But I keep getting this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find a build system compiler
```

I am not even sure what is a build system compiler? Which executable is that in the NDK? How do I specify it?

```
Running configure step for gmp-6.1.2
sh configure --enable-static --disable-shared --with-pic --prefix=C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/deps --with-sysroot=/C/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/sysroot --host=arm-linux-androideabi
configure: loading site script C:/msys64/mingw64/etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=32
checking whether C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang is gcc... yes
checking compiler C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang -Os -IC:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/deps/include -marm -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21 --sysroot=C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/sysroot ... yes
checking whether ARM gcc unsigned division works... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang accepts -g... yes
checking for C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang -E
checking build system compiler C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang... no
checking build system compiler C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang -Os -IC:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/deps/include -marm -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21 --sysroot=C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/sysroot ... no
checking build system compiler cc... no
checking build system compiler gcc... no
checking build system compiler c89... no
checking build system compiler c99... no
configure: error: Cannot find a build system compiler
Failed on configure step for gmp-6.1.2: sh configure --enable-static --disable-shared --with-pic --prefix=C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/deps --with-sysroot=/C/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/sysroot --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

Comment: GMP wants to build some programs that run on your windows machine, so it can run them to generate some tables, that will then be included in your android library. So it also needs a native compiler. At least that's how I understand the message. https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html#index-CC_005fFOR_005fBUILD

Comment: Try to find in log files why this step fails: `checking build system compiler C:/Developer/AppPlugin/build/android/toolchain-arm-21/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang... no`. The "configure" script leaves some logs. To check the compiler the configure script compiles some peace of code, and there should be a specific error in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set the as= command line option to my gcc executable.

Comment: what does this mean?